# useEffect always sets my addEventListener

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm new to hooks, I want to create an event listener for when a user clicks on a key on the document/window level.

The problem I'm facing, or what I don't understand is if and why the `useEffect` always needs to be called to re-set the eventListener?

I need to create a `keydown` event listener only once, but every state change recreates the event listener, or else, it just won't work:

```
function App() {
  const [pictureNumber, setPictureNumber] = useState(1);
  
  const setCurrentSlideData = e => setPictureNumber(e)

  const handleUserKeyPress = useCallback((e) => {
    if (e.code === "ArrowLeft") {
      setCurrentSlideData(pictureNumber - 1);
    }
    if (e.code === "ArrowRight") {
      setCurrentSlideData(pictureNumber + 1);
    }
  }, [pictureNumber]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("use effect called")
    window.addEventListener("keydown", handleUserKeyPress);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleUserKeyPress);
    };
  }, [handleUserKeyPress]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello, world {pictureNumber}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

See pen:
https://codepen.io/moshem/pen/NWNWzod

`use effect called` is logged for every key press even though the `handleUserKeyPress` is not supposed to change.

If I remove the `pictureNumber` dependency from `useCallback`, the counter changes only once for every key.

Am I doing it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to add `pictureNumber` to your dependency array for `useCallback`, instead, you can use the functional update for setting your state.

```
const handleUserKeyPress = useCallback((e) => {
  const setCurrentSlideData = e => setPictureNumber(e);
  
  if (e.code === "ArrowLeft") {
    setCurrentSlideData(prev => prev - 1);
  }
  if (e.code === "ArrowRight") {
    setCurrentSlideData(prev => prev + 1);
  }
}, []);
```

So, `pictureNumber` changes do not affect the recreation of this function.

In addition to that, actually you don't have to define `handleUserKeyPress` outside of your effect since you don't use it anywhere else. If you move it to your effect, you don't have to use `useCallback` anymore.

Also, you don't need a separate function to set `pictureNumber`, you can use the setter function directly. Here is a working one:

```js
function App() {
  const [pictureNumber, setPictureNumber] = React.useState(1);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("use effect called");
    
    function handleUserKeyPress(e) {
      if (e.code === "ArrowLeft") {
        setPictureNumber(prev => prev - 1);
      }
      if (e.code === "ArrowRight") {
        setPictureNumber(prev => prev + 1);
      }
    }

    window.addEventListener("keydown", handleUserKeyPress);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleUserKeyPress);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello, world {pictureNumber}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root" />
```

Comment: You should edit the first code block, setCurrentSlideData does not accept a callback, setPictureNumber does.

Comment: @abumalick, thanks for the comment but actually it works since the original function accepts a callback here :) You can test it.

Comment: Oh, this intermediate function disturbed me. I learned two things from you yesterday, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

### A simple solution with useState setter callback style

As @devserkan pointed out. We can use the previous state by passing a callback to `setState`. Thanks to this trick, we avoid a dependency to the state.

```js
const [pictureNumber, setPictureNumber] = useState(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("use effect called");
    
    const handleUserKeyPress = (e) => {
      if (e.code === "ArrowLeft") {
        setPictureNumber(prev => prev - 1);
      }
      if (e.code === "ArrowRight") {
        setPictureNumber(prev => prev + 1);
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("keydown", handleUserKeyPress);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleUserKeyPress);
    };
  }, [setPictureNumber]);
```

Here is official documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates

Here is a pen showing this solution: https://codepen.io/abumalick/pen/BaKaPgr

### Solution using a ref

This solution is a bit more complex, and would be useful when you need to change the handler function. We use a ref, the `useEffect` keeps a reference to the ref that does not change, and we can change the `current` property that changes.

The `useEffect` will be called only one time.

```js
  const [pictureNumber, setPictureNumber] = useState(1);

  const callbackRef = useRef(null);

  callbackRef.current = useCallback(
    (e) => {
      if (e.code === "ArrowLeft") {
        setPictureNumber(pictureNumber - 1);
      }
      if (e.code === "ArrowRight") {
        setPictureNumber(pictureNumber + 1);
      }
    },
    [pictureNumber, setPictureNumber]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleUserKeyPress = (e) => {
      callbackRef.current(e);
    };
    console.log("use effect called");
    window.addEventListener("keydown", handleUserKeyPress);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleUserKeyPress);
    };
  }, [callbackRef]);
```

Here is a codepen link: https://codepen.io/abumalick/pen/jOqOpLz